# CSS animation inside of input text?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to achieve is have a marquee inside of a input text, like blow;

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<marquee>Hi</marquee>" disabled></input>
```

I have tagged this as JavaScript as I don't think this is possible with just plain html, I could be mistaken however.

**EDIT** - Perhaps instead of the outdated `<marquee>` tag, I could use a CSS animation instead of the marquee to create the text scroll across the input.

Comment: First, the `<input>` tag has no closing `</input>`. Second, trying to insert `<marquee>` as HTML is as invalid as it gets. Third, it doesn't help that there is no such thing as a `<marquee>` element but that's another story.

Comment: I don't think all modern browsers even support marquee on its own. You could use a CSS animation to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Is there a previous question which outlines how this could be achieved then with a CSS animation? or would anyone care to share how this would be achieved with an alternative method?

Comment: That's another question. You would be best to delete this one and start over.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, the `<marquee>` element is not outdated. It just has never been part of any HTML standard ever. For compatibility reasons, the HTML5 spec marks it as obsolete. And current browsers only support it cause they did in the past. It can be removed, at any time, without notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS animations can mimic that functionality.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0% {text-indent:100%;}
    100% {text-indent:-10%}
}

input.marquee {
  -webkit-animation: marquee 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control marquee" value="Hi" disabled ></input>

<marquee>Hi</marquee>
```

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as `</input>` for a closing tag. https://developers.whatwg.org/the-input-element.html#the-input-element and, again, there is no such thing as a `<marquee>` element (but that's another story).

Comment: Only issue with this is that the % value is based on the input's width and not the character.  If you have a long string it will abruptly restart the animation near the input's width.

If only there was a CSS version of scrollwidth so we can see the actual overflowed amount and base text-indent off of that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with JS is this: change the value of the input and it looks like its moving...

```js
var marquu = document.getElementById('marquu');
var valLength = marquu.value.length;
var padding = 70;
var step = 0;
var originalString = marquu.value
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (step++ == 0) marquu.value = originalString;
  marquu.value = (valLength >= step) ? originalString.substr(valLength - step, valLength) : " " + marquu.value;
  
  if (step == padding) step = 0;
}, 100);
```

```html
<input id="marquu" type="text" value="Some String" disabled />
```