# CSS/jQuery/JS - slide in/out text input value

Tags: jquery, css

Just checking if anyone knows a cheeky way to animate a slide-out of the text in a HTML text input box with CSS or, perhaps more likely, jQuery.animate().
Since they aren't their own elements, I'm not sure they're available for manipulation other than the style properties available for the parent input box?
Not asking for code to be written, just want to either get my hopes crushed or pointed in a constructive direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of weird, but sure?  You could animate the text indent to get a "slide".

```css
#slideText {
  transition: text-indent 1s;
  text-indent: -100px;
}

#slideText:focus {
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="This is a test" id="slideText">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answers here: [CSS animation inside of input text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236105/css-animation-inside-of-input-text)

There are tricky solution to animate text with text-indent for example, but the text will be animated only inside text input from one edge to another.
To have animation from screen left/right side you will need to add custom markup, to animate DOM element with text inside.

In my opinion you shoudl use additional `<span>` with text you want to animate and animate it from screen edge to input element. When finished you can show input text and you will receive effect of text moving from screen edge to your input box.